# how this function inside 'sapply' do computation?

Tags: r

Can you help me explain what is sapply doing here ?

```
mylist<-list(v1=c('Group1','Group2','Group3'))

sapply( mylist , function(x) paste( head(x,-1) , tail(x,-1) , sep = " ") )
```

simple 'paste' will produce following result

```
paste(mylist)

output: [1] "c(\"Group1\", \"Group2\", \"Group3\")"
```

following is what i get when i use want to see head of 'mylist' using paste. class of this is a 'character'

```
paste(head(mylist))
[1] "c(\"Group1\", \"Group2\", \"Group3\")"


paste(head(mylist,-1))
character(0)

paste(tail(mylist,-1))
character(0)

paste(head(mylist,-1),tail(mylist,-1))
character(0)

paste(head(mylist,-1),tail(mylist,-1),sep=' ')
character(0)
```

now if i use the above command inside a function along with 'sapply' i get completely different result. I just want to know what is actually happening here.

```
sapply( mylist , function(x) paste( head(x,-1) , tail(x,-1) , sep = " ") )
v1             
[1,] "Group1 Group2"
[2,] "Group2 Group3"
```

as from my knowledge i know that when i use function inside 'sapply' it perform computation over every element of a vector. please tell me how computation is going on .

Comment: You have a list with a single list  element.  So, `sapply` is not need.  It will be used when there are multiple `list` elements. FOr example, you can extract the `list` as a `vector` with `v1 <- mylist[[1]]` and then do the `paste` i.e. `paste(head(v1,-1), tail(v1,-1), collapse=' ')`    For the original code,  `sapply( mylist , function(x) paste( head(x,-1) , tail(x,-1) , collapse = " ") )`

Comment: i want to know how it is working here.

Comment: Please check the `str(mylist)`.  You will understand the structure of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't seem to wish to try @akrun advices, here the details for you:

```
> mylist<-list(v1=c('Group1','Group2','Group3'))
> str(mylist)
List of 1
 $ v1: chr [1:3] "Group1" "Group2" "Group3"
> mylist
$v1
[1] "Group1" "Group2" "Group3"

> mylist[['v1']]
[1] "Group1" "Group2" "Group3"
```

What `sapply` does is to iterate over the elements of its first parameter, so in your case `x` become `mylist[[1]]` (and there will be only one iteration as `mylist` is a 1 element `list`, this element in turn is a 3 element `vector`.

I.e:

```
sapply( mylist , function(x) paste( head(x,-1) , tail(x,-1) , sep = " ") )
```

Is strictly equivalent to:

```
x <- mylist[[1]]; paste( head(x,-1) , tail(x,-1) , sep = " ")
```

As you have only one element in your list.

Comment: @akrun turned your comment in community wiki answer, probably easier to understand this way, feel free to review it if you feel I'm to light on the explanation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking pain to write the answer. I forgot to mark akrun's answer as correct one. now things become crystal clear.